# Problemas al Insertar datos a una base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo problemas al insertar información a mi base de datos

Método de la conexión:

```
//Variables para la conexión 
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Alumnos";
    public static final String USERNAME = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "Tecnologico";


    public static Connection getConection() {

        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión Exitosa");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return con;


    }
```

Código para subir datos a la base de datos:

```
//Botón que realiza la acción 
JButton btnSubirD = new JButton("Subir Datos");
        btnSubirD.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

//Inicio del código 
Connection con = null;


                try {

                    con = getConection();

                    ps= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Alumnos (No.Control,NombreAlumno,Telefono,Carrera,Fecha)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
                    ps.setString(1, tfNumero.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, tfNombre.getText());
                    ps.setString(3, tfTel.getText());
                    ps.setString(4, tfCarrera.getText());
                    ps.setString(5, tfFecha.getText());

                    int res = ps.executeUpdate();

                    if(res > 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guardado correctamente");
                        limpiarcajas();
                    }else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar los datos");
                    }


                    con.close();

                //Donde se genera el error  
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }
```

Este es el error que arroja al intentar subir los datos

> java.awt.event.ActionEvent[ACTION_PERFORMED,cmd=Subir
>   Datos,when=1569793900024,modifiers=Button1] on
>   javax.swing.JButton[,600,433,103x35,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@9f8e962,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Subir
>   Datos,defaultCapable=true]

Comment: ¿Ese es el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: ps.setString(1, tfNumero.getText());
como es el tipo de dato en la base de datos de "No.Control"?, si es un valor entero
deberias poner:
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(tfNumero.getText()));

Answer (score 0):

Una parte del INSERT tiene defectos de sintaxis para ser correcto. No respeta las normas de SQL.

Si bien es cierto que puedes crear nombres de objetos de BBD de cualquier forma, se recomienda NO usar ni caracteres extendidos, ni signos tales como puntos, comas, punto y coma, paréntesis, y todo otro símbolo que corresponda a acciones, comandos o parte de otras sintaxis, así como tampoco palabras reservadas.

En tu caso yo veo que has creado un nombre de columna "No.Control", pero lo invocas sin contenedores especiales, por lo que el intérprete de SQL lo analizará en base a la sintaxis ANSI, en la que el PUNTO es un separador usado para determinar la pertenencia de un objeto en otro, o más especificamente: BASE.TABLA y TABLA.COLUMNA...
Es MUY probable que haya un fallo de ejecución al momento de intentar la inserción.

Ahora bien, para mayor certeza, ¿qué DBMS estás usando?

Comment: estoy utilizando MySQL